# Pyqt: QTextCursor.WordUnderCursor not working as expected

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt

I am using `QTextCursor.WordUnderCursor` but it isn't working how I want it to, for example if I had:

> (text)

it will only give `(` OR `text` OR `)` not `(text)` which is what I want. It also doesn't work with commas, $, #, etc.

Is there any way I can get it to work with those characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QTextCursor.WordUnderCursor` considers a "word" to be an unbroken set of characters of the same class. I did some searching, and couldn't find how to change this behaviour.

However, it should be easy enough to get the word under the cursor, then progressively widening the selection using [`QTextCursor.setPostition()`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtextcursor.html#setPosition), checking if the new character is "acceptable" and then doing that for both sides (left and right).